# Is there a need to encrypt data when send over https?

Tags: encryption, tls, man-in-the-middle

I was monitoring web traffic from my Android mobile using Man in the middle proxy. I installed certificate signed from my server in my mobile and I could see all applications sending sensitive information like passwords as clear text.

I understand that SSL protocol takes care of establishing secure communication, but that eliminates any need to encrypt data? I could read all passwords sent by any application just by installing my certificate in the mobile.

Comment: Does an attacker have access to that same certificate? I'm not quite sure what you are asking. If you give away your private key, then of course your security is compromised.

Comment: Please add information about the proxy and how you configured it. Sometimes people incorrectly say certificate while a complete key store - including private key - is configured.

Comment: As long as you ensure that you're talking to the correct server (typically by properly validating the server's certificate), sending passwords in plain isn't a big issue. "just by installing my certificate" nobody stops you from shouting yourself in the foot. You could have "just installed a trojan horse", same thing really.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Should be "shooting" :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Apparently the OP has an unusually painful voice :) "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." -- "Don't do that."

Comment: There are three parts here: the browser on Android, the proxy, and the server. What exactly did you install on Android? Is this a certificate for the *server* or for the *proxy*? What did you install on the proxy? How did you arrange for the proxy to be a man-in-the-middle? If what you did was to tell Android to trust a certificate for which the proxy has the private key, then this is perfectly normal: you told Android to blindly trust your proxy. In other words, if that's what you did, you opened the door and are now complaining that the zombies are coming in. The solution is: don't do that.

Comment: So you can read your own passwords. This isn't *unauthorized* access; they're your passwords, you ought to be able to see them. If only you can attack you, that's not a vulnerability (it's a convoluted way to remember forgotten passwords).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because… somehow, this sounds like a job for Security.SE!

Comment: You do need additional encryption if you are using `TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA` of course :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a need to encrypt data when send over https?

*Maybe,* but it would not be practical for widespread consumer use.

In order for this extra encryption to be effective against [man-in-the-middle](/questions/tagged/man-in-the-middle) attacks, the client and server would already have had to agreed upon a pre shared secret out of band.

Comment: There is no *“maybe”* and encrypting data is practical… that’s what HTTPS practically does! SSL endpoints exchange secrets ad-hoc when establishing connections. After that, all data is communicated using the crypto algos they agreed upon during their handshake. See, the reason why Secure Socket Layers and HTTPS are embraced when exchanging sensible data is rooted in the fact that SSL works by communicating encrypted packets – which is what renders MITM attacks (and more) moot in the first place. Now… I’ll spare you the downvote, but I do urge you to either correct or delete your faulty answer.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the OP's question. He's asking if there is a need to encrypt within encryption - to which the answer is maybe. SSL can be decrypted by a MitM, corporations do it every day with a legitimate proxy - so your response that SSL "renders MitM attacks (and more) moot in the first place" is flat out *wrong*. Now good sir, I'll spare you the downvote (I can't downvote comments anyway) but I urge you to correct or delete your faulty comment. ;)

Comment: Again… there is no MITM on SSL. **Any MITM attacks on SSL are only possible if one of SSL's preconditions is broken.** (eg: server key was stolen, client trusts malign certificate without validation, CA had keys stolen or replaced, client got hacked and fake CA was injected to let it accept forged certificates, client fails to detect transparent rewrites from https into http links, etc.) Since breaking the preconditions of a protocol voids its assumed security, such precondition failures can not and are not classified as (or even considered to be) successful attacks on the SSL protocol itself.

Comment: Fun fact: if you would take the time to re-read the question yourself too, you’ld notice how OP not only has a difficulty understanding what OP has been monitoring with that “MITM proxy” – OP also describes failing one of the preconditions of the SSL protocol. (As I’m convinced you'll benefit from the learning experience, I’ll leave it to you to discover which of the preconditions OP failed. It’s pretty easy to spot actually.)

Comment: Again....you're wrong when stating "There is no MitM on SSL" Fun fact: POODLE and FREAK were precisely that - MitM attacks that leveraged flaws in the protocol implementation and the exploit conditions fall outside of the assumed preconditions that would void its assumed security. A legitimate corporate proxy also falls outside of your assumed preconditions.

Comment: *Padding Oracle On Downgraded Legacy Encryption* was not the result of a protocol failure; instead it was the result of a protocol implementation failure (CVE-2014-3566, CVE-2014-8730). And *Factoring RSA Export Keys* was merely possible because vendors kept supporting fallbacks for 512 Bit export keys which were maybe “safe” in the 90s, but not 20 years later. Again it was not a protocol fail but rather human failure as they chose to support weak keys; thereby violating preconditions that were already updated and well-vetted by the time some decided to dig old keys to exploit. (CVE-2015-0204)

Comment: But let’s stop the gentle discussion here as it’s getting rather long and according to SE rules it’s a bit of an abuse of the comment area. One thing’s for sure: we obviously disagree… and honestly, I don’t care enough to forward the discussion towards a chat room. If you ever happen to be able to find a paper actually pinpointing a weakness in the SSL protocol itself (not attacks resulting out of “incorrect protocol handling”), ***please*** be sure to drop a line around here. I’ld love to read such a paper… it would be a primer. 
// Oh, and before I press that button – Have a nice weekend! ;)

Comment: I shall agree to agree to disagree. :) It's obvious you're passionate about cryptography. I look forward to future discussions.

Comment: “I look forward to future discussions. ” – Same here. I’m pretty sure well stumble upon each other every now and then and I can certainly imagine there are many areas where we agree on things… sure hope we don’t get bored when we discover we agree on something. ;) As said, have a nice one!